# If $x,y,\alpha>0$ and $x>y$, then $x^\alpha>y^\alpha$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, functions, exponential-function

If $x,y,\alpha>0$ and $x>y$, then $x^\alpha>y^\alpha$
I know it's obvious when we use differnetation rule for exponential function, but I'm not allowed to.
Is there any way I can show it clearly?

Comment: What definition of $a^b$ are you working with? You can write it as $\exp(\alpha \log x) > \exp(\alpha \log y)$, and if you have proven $\exp(a) > \exp(b) \implies a > b$ then you can use that, and $\log x > \log y$ follows by substituting $(a, b) = (\log x, \log y)$.

Answer (score 4):

Hint:  Let $\displaystyle k = \frac{x}{y} \implies k > 1.$

How does $(ky)^\alpha$ compare with $y^\alpha$?

Answer (score 3):

To compare $x^\alpha$ and $y^\alpha$, we can divide the two. $(\frac{x}{y})^\alpha$ is what you get when you divide the two. Since $x>y$, $(\frac{x}{y})>1$. Also, $\alpha>0$. When we raise a number greater than $1$ to a power greater than $0$, we always get a number greater than $1$. Therefore, $(\frac{x}{y})^\alpha>1$. This implies that $x^\alpha>y^\alpha$.